# Broken images when hosting laravel in subfolder

Tags: hyperlink, laravel-5

So I have hosted my laravel app in a subfolder lets now refer the root of my project as subfolder. I have a constant base file which has header and footer of the website, I used link of images as

```
<img src="/img/img1.png">
```

so it goes to domain.com/img/img1.png instead of domain.com/subfolder/img/img1.png

and if I do

```
<img src="img/img1.png">
```

it works fine for the first page but when I navigate to subfolder/user/1 my images brake again because now they are finding images on subfolder/user/1/img/img1.png. I remember once I ran into such situation and someone helped me to set the path of images by adding one line in the header of the website but now I am not able to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Check your root Folder is correct

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this problem, make use of `asset()` or `url()` function:

```
<img src="{{ url(img/img1.png) }}">
```

Edit: if you plan to attach "subfolder" in url path, then try to edit .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/img/(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/subfolder/img/$1 [L,R=301]
```

The code above searches the image `/subfolder/img/img1.png` when `/img/img1.png` is found.

Comment: this isn't what I am looking for actually I want to tell my website that if I am referring /img/img1.png then instead of looking this img in maindomain.com/img/img1.png look for it in domain.com/subfolder/img/img1.png and there is a directive for that in html but I dont remember

Comment: did you mean .htaccess instead of html?